# Given $\lim _{n\to \infty} a_n = L$ ($L>0$), how to prove that $\lim_{n \to \infty} 1/a_n = 1/L$ without knowing the expression of $a_n$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

> Given positive sequence $a_n$ where $\lim _{n\to \infty} a_n = L, L >0$, prove using the [limit definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/(%CE%B5,_%CE%B4)-definition_of_limit) that $$\displaystyle{\lim _{n\to \infty}}\frac{1}{a_n} = \frac{1}{L}.$$

---

My **thoughts**:

How can I do this if I don't know how $a_n$ is defined? I can use the given limit to get the range of $a_n$ in terms of $L$, but I lack the direction to complete the proof.

Comment: You don't know the expression of $a_n$ though you know the limit as $n\to\infty$ is $L$.

Comment: That's a great question..and proving this theorem will give you a bit of insight: sometimes you don't need to know a "formula" for something to be able to prove something useful about it. Think of the chain rule: you don't know the formulas for $f$ and $g$, but you know that if they're differentiable at the right points, then $(f \circ g)'(x) = f'(g(x)) \cdot g'(x)$, which is pretty amazing!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to formally prove that if $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}a_n=\infty$, then $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{a_n}=0$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1150329/how-to-formally-prove-that-if-lim-limits-n-to-inftya-n-infty-then-li). Also, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1171733/convergence-of-inverse-of-convergent-sequence/1171755#1171755 and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/54754/proving-that-b-n-to-b-implies-left-frac1b-n-right-to-frac1b (A better duplicating target)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't know the expression of $a_n$ though you know the limit of the sequence as $n\to\infty$ is $L$, which gives you useful information:

- (1) the sequence $(a_n)$ is *bounded*;
- (2) $|a_n-L|$ is small when $n$ is large;
- (3) $a_n$ is *away* from $0$ when $n$ is large since $L>0$.

Note that 
$$
\left|\frac{1}{a_n}-\frac{1}{L}\right|=\frac{|a_n-L|}{|a_n|\cdot L}.
$$

You want to show that this quantity is small for large $n$. Well, you can make the numerator small by (2). Now use (3) to show that $1/|a_n|$ cannot be too big.